# Clear WebGL2RenderingContext from canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, webgl2

I have a WebGL canvas which I want to clear at a certain point which uses a WebGL2RenderingContext and I can't seem to find a way to either:

- Clear the canvas
- Replace the context with a different context
- Remove the context altogether

I have tried something like this, and while it allows me to get the canvas and it's context, I'm now not sure where to go from here

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('#canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
gl.clear();
```

I have also tried something like this to overwrite the canvas with a new context but it didn't seem to work.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('#canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('2d');
gl.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I would like it to be so that the canvas itself is still on the page but just not have anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the context of a canvas.

You can clear a WebGL or WebGL2 canvas with

```
 const red = 1;
 const green = 0.5;
 const blue = 0.7;
 const alpha = 1;
 gl.clearColor(red, green, blue, alpha);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```